# Retrieving and Moving Files in a Folder with more than 5000 files in it using C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, list-view-threshold

I currently have a folder with more than 5000 files in it, so when I open the folder to view the files inside it through the UI I get the classic "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold" error.

So I'm trying to split up the files into separate subfolders so I can access them, however when I try to use the SharePoint C# Client to access these files to move I get the same error, no matter what method I use.

Attempt #1 (Navigating to the files using the Folder and File objects)

```
                sharePointOnlineContext.Load(folderWithMoreThan5000Items, x => x.Folders, x => x.ServerRelativeUrl);
                sharePointOnlineContext.ExecuteQuery();

                var fileList = folderWithMoreThan5000Items.Files.Take(1000);
sharePointOnlineContext.Load(correspondenceArchiveFolder, x => x.Files, x => x.ServerRelativeUrl);
                sharePointOnlineContext.ExecuteQuery();


                foreach (var file in fileList)
                {
                    sharePointOnlineContext.Load(file.ListItemAllFields);
                    sharePointOnlineContext.ExecuteQuery();                
                    file.MoveTo("NewFolderName", MoveOperations.Overwrite);
                }
```

This fails on the ExecuteQuery after it tries to load the folder with more than 5000 items saying "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold"

Attempt #2 (Navigating to the files using ListItems and CAML queries)

```
 List containingList = sharePointOnlineContext.Web.GetList("https://sharepoint.com/sites/RootSiteFolder/account/CustomerName/FolderWithOver5000FilesInIt");

            ListItemCollectionPosition itemPosition = null;

                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();

                camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = itemPosition;

                camlQuery.ViewXml =
                  $@"<View Scope = 'RecursiveAll'>
                                       <Query>
                                       <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Text'>'/account/CustomerName/FolderWithOver5000FilesInIt'</Value></Eq></Where>
                                       </Query>
                                        <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/> <FieldRef Name='Name'/><FieldRef Name='Body'/>
                                        </ViewFields><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit>
                                        </View>";

                ListItemCollection collListItem = containingList.GetItems(camlQuery);

                sharePointOnlineContext.Load(collListItem);

                sharePointOnlineContext.ExecuteQuery();

                itemPosition = collListItem.ListItemCollectionPosition;

                var listItems = containingList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                sharePointOnlineContext.Load(listItems, items => items.Include(item => item.File));
                sharePointOnlineContext.ExecuteQuery();

                Console.WriteLine($"item count : {collListItem.Count}");
```

This also fails, if I have the FileDirRef filter in the CAML Query pointed to the name of the Folder it fails on the `ExecuteQuery()` after I load `CollListItem` with the "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold" error.

If I remove the FileDirRef filter in the CAML Query then the query works and returns 1000 items as the RowLimit suggests but it retrieves files from the root Site folder (https://sharepoint.com/sites/RootSiteFolder) as opposed to files from my desired folder (https://sharepoint.com/sites/RootSiteFolder/account/CustomerName/FolderWithOver5000FilesInIt).

As such, this is useless as the initial item count before the filter is 250k+ files.

Can I modify any of the above approaches to retrieve and then move all the files from my desired folder or do I need to use a different approach to retrieve the desired files?